# Need SQL query for below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to come up with an SQL query which will retrieve the maximum "seq" column from table1 if the corresponding "seq" column has no "C" in "Res" column in table2

**Scenario:1**

```
Table 1
+----+---------+
| Seq | Req    | 
+----+---------+
| 001 | X1     |
| 002 | X1     |
| 003 | X1     |
+----+---------+

Table2
+----+---------+--------+
|Seq | Req     | Res    | 
+----+---------+--------+
| 001| X1     |   D     | 
| 002| X1     |   D     |
| 003| X1     |   C     |
+----+---------+--------+
```

output : As the maximum seq (003) has 'C' in Res , I dont want to display any records here

**Scenario:2**

```
Table 1
+----+---------+
| Seq | Req    | 
+----+---------+
| 001 | X1     |
| 002 | X1     |
| 003 | X1     |
| 004 | X1     |
+----+---------+

Table2
+----+---------+--------+
|Seq | Req     | Res    | 
+----+---------+--------+
| 001| X1     |   D     | 
| 002| X1     |   D     |
| 003| X1     |   C     |
+----+---------+--------+
```

output :  I want to display record "004,X1" from Table-1 as there is no "C" in Res column for maximum seq(004) in Table2 ( No record exists in Table2 for max seq - 004

**Scenario:3**

```
Table 1
+----+---------+
| Seq | Req    | 
+----+---------+
| 001 | X1     |
| 002 | X1     |
| 003 | X1     |
| 004 | X1     |
+----+---------+

Table2
+----+---------+--------+
|Seq | Req     | Res    | 
+----+---------+--------+
| 001| X1     |   D     | 
| 002| X1     |   D     |
| 003| X1     |   C     |
| 004| X1     |   K     |
+----+---------+--------+
```

output :  I want to display record "004,X1" from Table-1 as there is no "C" in Res column for maximum seq(004) in Table2 .Max Seq Number in Table2 (004) is K

Tried with inner join and left join  , but one or the other scenario fails. 
Please help me with this

Comment: please include the queries you tried which failed. Show the effort in order for it to be a good question :)

Comment: ```select * from  
(select req reqq, max(seq) reqin from tabl1  group by req_no) x , 
table2 y  where  x.reqq = y.req and (y.seq is null or x.reqin = y.seq) 
and y.res!= 'C' and x.reqq = 'X1';
 ```
This is failing in Scenario-2



```
select w1.seq,w1.req from table1 w1 inner join 
(select a.req as reqno ,max(a.seq) as sequ from table1 a left join table2 b 
on a.seq = b.seq and a.req = b.req  and b.res !='C' group by a.req ) d
on w1.req = d.reqno and w1.seq = d.sequ and w1.req = 'X1';
```
This is failing in scenario-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be slightly different in Oracle SQL

```
SELECT seq, req 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE seq in (SELECT max(seq) FROM table1) 
        AND seq NOT IN (SELECT seq FROM table2 WHERE res = 'C')
```

Comment: hi , can you help me with a query if i have to give a where condition with list of req like while req in ('X1','X2','X3')
and the query should return Req and highest seq
o/p : X1 01
       X2 03

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question. `WHERE req in ('X1', 'X2', 'X3')` is straightforward. If you want the highest `seq` for each `req`, then in general you will need something like `JOIN (SELECT req, max(seq) seq FROM table1 GROUP BY req)  r ON table1.req = m.seq` to make a table of those values available in your query.

Answer (score 1):

try lik below

```
with cte as
(
 select *,row_number() over(order by seq desc) rn
 from table1
)    
select cte.* 
from cte left join table2 t2 on cte.seq=t2.seq
where t2.res<>'C' and cte.rn=1
```

Comment: your query is returning no rows when SEQ=004 and RES=C.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17daadb01108095c5113cba1f513c54c check this link please . here i tested and working fine

Comment: Please check the link: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27bc27ff47b319c484b9cd314fef7e17) where I have just changed last two inserts in table2 for creating the scenario: SEQ=004 and RES=C ..

It is not working..

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 according to  your logic this should not returned any result and my query does showing anything which is correct cause in table2 max seq C exists

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 your quotation "output : As the maximum seq (003) has 'C' in Res , I dont want to display any records here"

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (SEQ, REQ) AS
  SELECT '001', 'X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'X1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'X3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'X4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (SEQ, REQ, RES) AS
  SELECT '001', 'X1', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X1', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X1', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'X1', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X2', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X2', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X2', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X3', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X3', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X3', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'X3', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL

  SELECT '001', 'X4', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'X4', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'X4', 'C' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT SEQ, REQ
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.*,
         MAX( t1.SEQ ) OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.REQ ) AS max_seq,
         MAX( t2.RES ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t1.SEQ )
                       OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.REQ ) AS max_res
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
         ON ( t1.seq = t2.seq AND t1.req = t2.req )
)
WHERE  SEQ = max_seq
AND    max_res = 'C'
```

**Output**:

```
SEQ | REQ
:-- | :--
004 | X1 
003 | X2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bafe3fd3d64842839aef86d403b0bbb1)*

Comment: Hi, I need output as below. can you please help. Also , i am using Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit)
X3 004
X4 004
Also i want use a condition like where seq in ('X1','X2','X3','X4')